# How to update a pull request if pull request already checked out locally?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, pull-request

So I first forked a repo and then made a commit to that forked repo. I then opened a pull request. The pull request listed all the changes I wanted.

Reviewer checkout my Pull Request on his local system by making these commands:

```
$ git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
$ git checkout BRANCHNAME
```

After reviewing my pull request, there were a number of changes that the repo owner wanted me to make before he accepted it. I have made those changes in my fork and then i pushed changes in already opened Pull Request.

Now, how repo owner / reviewer will get my changes in already checked out pull request?

Comment: If you pushed your changes to the branch from where the origin Pull request is created then Pull is supposed to be update automatically.

Comment: "git pull" will be sufficient. it updates that respective pull request also.

Comment: git pull not working. Its giving this error:

There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> MyBranch

Comment: @msmq so your forked repo seems store as the remote name is `upstream` in the repo owner/reviewer's local git repo (`git remote add <fork repo URL>`).

Answer (score 0):

Update using [git-pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), as follows:

```
git pull origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
git checkout BRANCHNAME
```

Or you could set it up as an upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/BRANCHNAME BRANCHNAME
git pull
```

Comment: git fetch upstream pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME not working
BUT
git pull upstream pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME is working to update specific Pull Request.